# If/else macros behaving differently with BOOL than with numbers

Tags: objective-c, macros

I have the following code which works properly:

```
#define TEST 0

#if TEST == 1
    #define URL @"example.com"
#else
    #define URL @"not-example.com"
#endif
```

So in this scenario, `URL` will be `not-example.com` as expected.

Now, I want to use BOOL instead of 0 and 1. However, when I try the following code, it gives me the wrong answer:

```
#define TEST NO

#if TEST == YES
    #define URL @"example.com"
#else
    #define URL @"not-example.com"
#endif
```

This gives me `URL` equal to `example.com`. The **same answer** is given if `TEST` is set to `YES`.

Why is using a BOOL different than using a number in macros?

Comment: VERY strange behavior - can even be reduced to `#if NO == YES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor is the standard *C* preprocessor and works on very limited expressions made up from numeric constants. Any non-macro identifier in a preprocessor expression is treated as having the value `0`.

The Objective-C `NO` is not a macro for a number but for `_objc_no`, and that is not a number but a non-macro identifier - so in a conditional expression it would be treated as `0`. Same for `YES`.

So your:

```
#if TEST == YES
```

turns out to be:

```
#if 0 == 0
```

whether `TEST` is `YES` or `NO`.

For more details see [C Preproccesor: Conditionals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_4.html) (From GCC, but the same applies to Clang/Xcode and other C compilers.)